# Read data (large file) in R causes: InPageError, Error Status Code: c000009c, Faulting Media Type: 00000003

Tags: hard-drive, memory, rstudio

I want to load a big data set (6GB) in R (or Rstudio), as I do on my other (W10) computers. (My setup: W10 64bit, 36GB RAM, C:\PageFile.Sys 5GB, C:\SwapFile.Sys 16 MB). However: rsession.exe crashes with the following error message:

Source
RStudio R Session

Summary
Stopped working

Date
‎01.‎11.‎2019 11:32

Status
Report sent

Description
Faulting Application Path:  C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\rsession.exe

**Problem signature**
Problem Event Name: InPageError
Error Status Code:  c000009c
Faulting Media Type:    00000003
OS Version: 10.0.18362.2.0.0.768.101
Locale ID:  1031
Additional Information 1:   b71d
Additional Information 2:   b71d8101b6bd282ea0fc6ccefaf1d923
Additional Information 3:   cab4
Additional Information 4:   cab4704ae78e462d34c9edc6b1e89123

**Extra information about the problem**
Bucket ID:  7d2749361dc05922d6a071409bc80d44 (470146)

---

**I searched the web**: There is nothing exactly the same, but many old posts on W7 with similar error codes, but different applications and no common understanding how to fix it. Might be a messed up Windows installation, RAM or hard drive error or ... So I'm trying the annoying step by step error exclusion.

**I tried the following:**

- Reinstall R and Rstudio
- try different ways to read the data (read.csv, read_csv etc.)
- Windows Memory Diagnostic: "The Windows Memory Diagnostic tested the computer's memory and detected no errors"
- CHKDSK: "Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems."
- Running a Western Digital HDD diagnostics tool (extended test), which ended after several hours with "**FAIL** Too many bad sectors detected - Test stopped with errors(s)." :-( Seems like I need a new hard drive!
- I tried to read the data from an external hard, which works, thus I gonna exchange my hard drive and assume the problem will be fixed.
- My next steps would have been:

  - boot Ubuntu and try to read the data from there (exclude Windows error)
  - run more in-depth diagnostics on my RAM
  - Restore Windows to a restore point
  - Repair Windows
  - Reinstall Windows
  - test individual RAM blocks by leaving only one of them in the computer
  - Buy a new computer
  - Change my job

Comment: How Big is your Big Data? How much Random Access Memory does your Machine have? How much Virtual Memory does your Operating System Software Installation have? What is the Size of your "`C:\PageFile.Sys`" File and of your "`C:\SwapFile.Sys`" File? Have you researched the InterNet for the "_InPageError_" Problem Event and for the "`c000009c`" Error Status Code?

Comment: question edited according to your suggestions

Comment: Great. This is maybe the third time when we are uttering these words, @MrGISRocker, so they may be sounding just like a cliché: you need to find an expert in the `R` Statistical Programming Language. Try to find a community concerned to it and see if you can point them toward your question.

Comment: Also, we have just noticed your Side Note: "_as I do on my other computers_". Regardless of the fact that your other computers may contain _MicroSoft_ _Windows_ **10** Operating System Software Installations in them or not, this one does. So we are dealing again with this version, from which we really cannot expect much good to come. The cause of your issue might be related to a weird and difficult to debug way in which this version handles the _RStudio_ Static Software Application, as it seems to be handling mostly everything nowadays.

Comment: @ DOBRESCU_Mihai: I guess the the problem is very unlikely related to R. I'm an R expert and loading data is a very basic operation. All my computers run on W10.

Comment: We are finally happy to meet an `R` Expert, @MrGISRocker. If all of your computers are running the _MicroSoft_ _Windows_ **10** Operating System, then we are again there: a Version that has got so sophisticated during the latest more than four years of existence that even Very Basic Loading Data Operations are still producing issues. Why should we be surprised that a question related to Deleting Data Operations have drawn 40,000 views only in three days? Most of the people with whom we have been talking are suggesting Clean ReInstallation Procedures in such weird and intricate situations.

Comment: I like your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among other issues, HDD errors can cause the problem. In my case the HDD needs to be exchanges. Other possible options for the error may be described above.